# Emacs Lisp Regular Expression Match everything until character sequence

Tags: regex, emacs, elisp

I am trying to write a regular expression in emacs lisp that will match multi line comments.

For example:

```
{-
  Some

  Comment

  Here
-}
```

Should match as a comment. Basically, anything between {- and -}. I am able to almost do it by doing the following:

`"\{\-[^-]*\-\}"`

However, this will fail if the comment includes a `-` not immediately followed by `}`

So, it will not match correctly in this case:

```
{-
  Some -
  Comment -
  Here -
-}
```

Which should be valid.

Basically, I would like to match on everything (including newlines) up to the sequence `-}`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See if this works for you: `{-[[:unibyte:]]+?-}`

Comment: If you submit that as a solution, I will award it to you. Otherwise, I will add it myself.

Comment: On additional consideration, this solution still does not work for some more complex comments.

Comment: If you still haven't resolved it, update you post with an example of what it didn't match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't this work for you?  `{-[^-]*[^}]*-}`

(You didn't specify things precisely, so I'm just guessing what you want. Must the `{-` and `-}` be at the line beginning? Must they be on lines by themselves? Must there be some other characters between them?  Etc.  For example, should it match a line like this? `{--}`?)

Answer (score 1):

Made a toolkit for such cases. It comes with a parser, beg-end.el.

Remains to write a function, which will determine the beginning resp. the end of the object.

In pseudo-code:

```
(put 'MY-FORM 'beginning-op-at
           (lambda () (search-forward "-}")))

(put 'MY-FORM 'end-op-at
     (lambda () (search-backward "{-")))
```

When done, it's should be available, i.e. copied and returned like this

```
(defun MY-FORM-atpt (&optional arg)
  " "
  (interactive "p")
  (ar-th 'MY-FORM arg))
```

Get it here:

https://launchpad.net/s-x-emacs-werkstatt/

Comment: Does this return a regular expression? I am trying to use this with font-lock highlighting so it must be in the form of a regular expression.

Comment: @Joe Example shown returns the string matched. Emacs-Werkstatt delivers related functions, which deliver beg-end positions etc. When searching a form defined by beginning and end, which spans an arbitrary number of lines,  reg-exps can't match that reliably. A parser is needed. MY-FORM-atpt would call the parser on MY-FORM, reading the definitions. BTW the real case would ask if already at beginning, i.e. looking at "{-" - the lambda must be extended still. Also you will ask if it should match inside a string. Basically it should be useable to fontify any section found.